# WPF: Binding an integer to a TextBlock with TemplateBinding

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, controltemplate

I have a custom control in WPF. In this I have a `DependencyProperty` of the type `int`. In the template for the custom control I have a `TextBlock`, I and would like to show the value of the integer in the `TextBlock`. But I can't get it to work.

I'm using `TemplateBinding`. If I use the same code but change the type of the `DependencyProperty` to `string` it works fine. But I really want it to be an integer for the rest of my application to work.

How can I do this?

I've written simplified code that shows the problem. First the custom control:

```
public class MyCustomControl : Control
{
    static MyCustomControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl)));

        MyIntegerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyInteger", typeof(int), typeof(MyCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0));
    }


    public int MyInteger
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(MyCustomControl.MyIntegerProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MyCustomControl.MyIntegerProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyIntegerProperty;
}
```

And this is my default template:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Azure">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding MyInteger}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And usage:

```
<Window x:Class="CustomControlBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControlBinding"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <local:MyCustomControl Width="100" Height="100" MyInteger="456" />
</Grid>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks // David

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try using a regular `Binding` with a `RelativeSource` of `TemplatedParent`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyInteger, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

According to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/edec50f6-d1c7-4891-a814-a9c6f154baf9), this is a limitation of `TemplateBinding`:

> TemplateBinding is a lightweight
>   "binding", it doesn't support some
>   features of traditional Binding, such
>   as automatically type conversion using
>   the known type converters associated
>   with the target property

Comment: Using regular Binding like this you can also specify your own value converter (see IValueConverter) which you can code your own type conversion behavior.

Comment: Works great! Thank you Quartermeister! :)

Comment: @Aardvark: Good point.  You can actually specify a Converter even if you use a TemplateBinding.

Comment: I *think* Silverlight's version of TemplateBinding doesn't support a Converter parameter - but I guess WPF does. My mistake!

Comment: Wow this is life saver!

The sad part: This isn't automatically and properly handled in Microsoft Expression Blend 4